# How to update all the columns of a dataframe in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

In scala we can update all the columns of a dataframe with the help of below

```
val outputDF = InputDF.select(InputDF.columns.map(c => toLower(col(c))):_*)
```

How to handle the above scenario in Java in an immutable way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be pretty the same:

```
inputDF.select(Arrays.stream(inputDF.columns()).map(c ->lower(col(c))).toArray(Column[]::new));
```

You can also do it with a loop:

```
    Dataset outputDF = inputDF;
    for (String c : inputDF.columns()){
        outputDF = outputDF.withColumn(c, lower(col(c)));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I will use a loop to iterate through each column and do the operation in a mutable fashion will there be any side effect

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a loop as well (see my edited answer), no side effects.